# creation of Dynamic Components in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

i want to creat a  dynamic component in react from json,
any idea ?

for the moment i try to generate them like that

```
 getMenu(){
  var pages  = {
        name : "Parcs",
        title : "Bienvenue sur la parc toto",
        Components : [
            "HeaderSocial",
            "HeaderFull",
            "Menu",
            "ParcsSlider",
            "TabMenu",
            "Footer"
        ],
    }

    var panel = [];
    var tmp;


    for (let i = 0; i <Object.keys(pages.Components).length; i++){

        tmp = Object(pages.Components)[i];
        panel.push('<' +  {tmp} + "/>");
    }
    console.log(panel)
    return (panel);
}
```

this example fail ... any idea ?

Comment: In this `Object.keys(pages.Components).length`, what is the purpose of `Object.keys`? Its an array. You can directly do `pages.component.length`

Answer (score 2):

Issues :

`Object.keys(pages.Components)` -> This is already array so why are you using `Object.keys()` ?

`'<' +  {tmp} + "/>"`  , this should be `'<' +  tmp + "/>"`

Change for loop

```
for (let i = 0; i <Object.keys(pages.Components).length; i++){
    tmp = Object(pages.Components)[i];
    panel.push('<' +  {tmp} + "/>");
}
```

To

```
for (let i = 0; i < pages.Components.length; i++){
    panel.push(React.createElement(pages.Components[i])));
}
```

OR Simply (as @Rajesh suggested in comment )

```
return pages.Component.map(x=> React.createElement(pages.Components[i])))
```

Comment: You can replace *To* code to `pages.Component.map(x=> \`<${x}/>\`)`

Comment: hello i get for result <function HeaderSocial() { _classCallCheck(this, HeaderSocial); return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (HeaderSocial.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(HeaderSocial)).apply(this, arguments)); }/>

Comment: Will you please create one plnkr for this ? have you imported all the componenets in that file?

Comment: i fix it :) with  for (let i = 0; i < pages.Components.length; i++){
           panel.push( React.createElement(pages.Components[i]));
        }
        return (panel);

Comment: sure in 50 min (time for new upvote) ty ps can you edit your anwser with my complement ? React.createElement(pages.Components[i]))

Comment: @tetar , yes I have made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to create an string element list you have to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to append that string you manipulate to the actual component. And rather than going into a separate method to do the manipulation you could use a 'map'.

Here I have added the code as well as the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zu4pqk0/). But there are better ways of using conditional rendering to achieve this kind of dynamic behavior inside a component.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state= {
         pages: {
           name : "Parcs",
           title : "Bienvenue sur la parc toto",
           components : [
             "div",
             "span",
             "p",
             "i"
           ],
         }
      };
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={
            {
                __html: this.state.pages.components.map((item, i) => {
                        return '<' + item + '>' +  'test data' + '</' + item + '>';  
            })
        }
     }></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use different approach, change from array of string to array of function instead.

Since React JSX can create as functional components, you can call it as normal function.

```
var pages  = {
        name : "Parcs",
        title : "Bienvenue sur la parc toto",
        Components : [
            HeaderSocial,
            HeaderFull,
            Menu,
            ParcsSlider,
            TabMenu,
            Footer
        ],
    }
```

and you can call it like this

```
page.Components.map(jsx => jsx({ ...props }))
```

example:

```
const x = ({ num }) => <span>{num} </span>
const y = ({ num }) => <span>{num + 1}</span>
const arr = [x, y]
```

then

```
const JSXComponent = ({ num }) => (
  <div>{arr.map(jsx => jsx({ num }))</div>
)
JSXComponent({ num: 1 })  // 1 2
```

you can even inject `...props` to your components too. :)